# Emploi du "en temps voulu"

Tags: traduction, anglais, locutions

I have three questions for the locution "en temps voulu".

1. Can one use it colloquially?
2. Can it convey, as found here: https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/en+temps+voulu.html, the meaning of "[in due time](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20due%20time)"?
3. Is it considered very formal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that while there is indeed the possible meaning of "in due time" or "from a timely manner", when for example you need to submit something before a given date, this expression is also often used as a more "elegant" way of saying "later":

> Je sais que nous devons encore faire cela, mais nous nous en occuperons en temps voulu.

> I know we still need to do that, but we'll take care of it later.

Was it that usage or the other one, both are rather formal from where I see it. I'd rather use it in a professional / administrative setup but could use it with my friends and family without sounding too weird.

Answer (score 1):

This locution can be used in everyday speech but as well  in formal writing, to the contrary of what a former answer asserts.  What is colloquial in the way of a locution constructed with "voulu" is  the locution "c'est voulu", which is to be found under "**A**" below.

> ([LFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/voulu))   Loc. fam. C'est voulu : C'est fait exprès, ce n'est pas un hasard.

"En temps voulu" is not unique as a locution to be constructed with "voulu"; there is a whole family of such locutions, first of all the synonymous "au moment voulu", which register is the same. In fact it is a freely constructive family. This is so because "voulu" is an adjective, a full fledged adjective, and so you can construct all sorts of noun phrases with it. Below,  "**B**" is the relevant  meaning.

> ([TLFi, **II**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/voulu)) **A.** − Qui est fait, réalisé, obtenu volontairement.
>                **B.** − Qui est commandé, requis, imposé par les circonstances.

- les conditions voulues, les ingrédients voulus, la personne voulue, le ministre voulu, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is colloquial and not excessively formal. In due course. Perhaps also: In the fullness of time.